# javascript functions doestnt work after using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using this jquery to have spell check on the textarea. Spell check works fine but after using jquery for spell check my other javascript functions are not working. Any idea why ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $Spelling.SpellCheckAsYouType('txt_comment1');
    function showselected() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById('txt_comment1');
        var startPos = input1.selectionStart;
        var endPos = input1.selectionEnd;
        var doc = document.selection;

        if (doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0) {
            alert(doc.createRange().text);
        } else if (!doc && input1.value.substring(startPos, endPos).length != 0) {
            document.getElementById('txt_addwords').value = input1.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
            //alert(input1.value.substring(startPos, endPos))
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Button 
    ID="cmd_submit_good" 
    runat="server" 
    Height="38px" 
    OnClientClick="showselected();" 
    onclick="cmd_submit_good_Click" 
    Text="Good Word" 
    Font-Bold="False" 
    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" 
    Width="80px" />
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console via Chrome?

Comment: No i dont have any errors, its just function showselected is not working.

Comment: It doesn't say if the function doesn't exist or anything? Post some more code, as this much doesn't seem to help us identify the issue.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { //jquery/javascript code here});`

Comment: It has something to do with postback, showselected function is to get the selected text from textarea and save it in "txt_addwords" textbox, but due to spell check it goes into postback and the value of txt_addwords textbox becomes empty. I have tried the above thing it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/calling-a-script-when-button-clicked, I got the answer fro
this link. Jquery transforms the actual text box that is why javascript wasnt executing on the original text box.